# How can I ask this query in SQL?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database, oracle

For each department view the name of the researchers and the number of contracts entered into by researchers that have been exclusively responsible for contracts with 'importi' greater than $100000 and 'aziende' that have descriptor type 'TypeA = 'Grandi Aziende'.

This is the database description:

```
DIPARTIMENTO(CodD*, NomeD, Settore-Scientifico, Università)
RICERCATORE(CodR*, Nome, Cognome, DataNascita, CodD, DataPresaServizio)
AZIENDA(CodA*, NomeA, TipoA, Citt`a, Settore-Industriale)
CONTRATTO-DI-RICERCA(CodR-ResponsabileScientifico*, CodA*, DataInizio*,
Durata, Importo)
```

This is the query I've come up with:

```sql
SELECT Nome, Count(R1.CodR) AS 'Numero Contratti'
FROM RICERCATORE AS R1,DIPARTIMENTO AS D1
WHERE R1.CodD = D1.CodD
AND R1.CodR IN (SELECT R2.CodR
                FROM RICERCATORE AS R2, CONTRATTO-DI-RICERCA AS C1
                WHERE R2.CodR = C1.CodR-ResponsabileScientifico
                AND R2.CodR NOT IN (SELECT C2.CodR-ResponsabileScientifico 
                                    FROM CONTRATTO-DI-RICERCA AS C2
                                    WHERE  C2.Importo <= 100000
                                    OR C2.CodA IN (SELECT A1.CodA
                                                      FROM AZIENDA AS A1
                                                      WHERE A1.TipoA <> 
                                                   'Grande Azienda')))
GROUP BY D1.CodD
```

Is this correct? IS there a simpler way maybe to formulate the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just link the tables and filter out what you don't want.  I'm using count(distinct) in case you have one-to-many relationships in your tables.

```
SELECT r.Nome, Count(Distinct r.CodR) 'Numero Contratti'
FROM CONTRATTO-DI-RICERCA c
INNER JOIN RICERCATORE r ON c.CodR-ResponsabileScientifico=r.CodR
INNER JOIN AZIENDA a ON c.CodA=a.CodA
INNER JOIN DIPARTIMENTO d ON r.CodD=d.CodD
WHERE c.Implorto > 100000
AND a.TipoA='Grande Azienda'
GROUP BY r.Nome
```

Comment: Ok, but isn't there a problem with the exclusivity? meaning there could be names of researchers that have also done contracts with 'Importo <100000' right? And if I wanted to see for each department I can just add a group by at the end?

Comment: the c.Importo>100000 will filter out any records <100000, so you are good there.  you're right--I forgot the group by (i updated the query to add this)

Comment: Oh so the join assures I have people that have strictly only worked on contracts with that importo>100000. Thanks!